# AssemblyInitialize not measured in Code Coverage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest, code-coverage

I came across some strange results when using Code Coverage for our unit tests.

In the `AssemblyInitialize` function we do some initialization work (like `AutoMapper`, `AbstractFactories`) and this function is correctly executed.

The strange thing is that Code Coverage shows that there is no coverage for the functions that are called from `AssemblyInitialize`. Is this by design or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with as by-design it seems too specific to be anything other. As someone who is looking into doing similar for an open source coverage tool it seems odd for this to be an accident and would be a very unusual bug.

The TDD purist in me would say this is because the setup/teardown of any type (assembly/class) is not actually part of the test itself and so should not be included in coverage. You should instead have separate, specific tests for that code rather than rely on the test setup/initialization failing.

Other .NET tools ([dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) for one) does coverage by test and 'may' also exclude results gained whilst running such setups; this is conjecture rather than known fact though.

Comment: Yeah.. maybe I should create a separate unit test for it. But the code is not really fast (Automapper.Configure for example takes a long time when you only run 1 test).. Thanks for the input. I also can't imagine being it a bug or something... so it's probably more a conceptual thing.